# How to organize minitest/unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

After using RSpec for several projects, I'm giving minitest/unit a go. I'm liking it so far, but I miss using describe/context blocks to group my tests/specs in a logical way.

I know minitest/spec provides this functionality, but I like that minitest/unit feels a bit closer to barebones Ruby.

Are there any gems that provide describe/context support for minitest/unit? Or, should I just live with my long, unorganized test files in minitest/unit?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I know several folks coming from RSpec to minitest struggling with the same question. They love the ability to nest using describe/context blocks and want to continue in minitest. There are several solutions:

1. Use minitest's spec DSL: While there are minor differences, the spec DSL gives you most (all?) of the good parts of the rspec DSL. The big difference is the lack of `context` blocks. But you can just as easily use `describe` in its place and everything works as you'd expect.
2. Use directories and files: I prefer this option. I dislike scrolling through a 300 line test file, regardless whether its using the spec DSL or the classical xUnit style. I do not find nesting unrelated tests helpful. The same rules for comprehension for code applies to tests. So break it up. Create a directory and place several files within it.

Here is an example of how my test files are organized:

```
test/
     models/
            user/
                 authentication_test.rb
                 email_test.rb
                 reservation_test.rb
                 user_test.rb
                 username_test.rb
```

I use this structure whether I'm using the spec DSL or the xUnit style. When using the spec DSL I specify what I'm testing in my describe block like so:

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe User, :authentications do

  before do
    # ...
```

Answer (score 28):

You can also throw multiple classes into one test file:

```
module PizzaTest
  class Isolation < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    test "is awesome by default" do
      assert Pizza.new.awesome?
    end
  end

  class Integration < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    fixtures :all

    test "is awesome too" do
      pizzas('one-with-everything').awesome?
    end
  end
end
```

and even nest test classes:

```
class PizzaTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "is awesome by default" do
    assert Pizza.new.awesome?
  end

  class Integration < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    fixtures :all

    test "is awesome too" do
      assert pizzas('one-with-everything').awesome?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 24):

I prefer this way (only a little bit) but I think it easier to follow:

```
class ConventionalNameTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  class ContextTest < ConventionalNameTest
    # so much stuff...
  end
  class AnotherContextTest < ConventionalNameTest
    # and some more...
  end
```

Comment: to be able to define `setup` multiple times in one test file, and stay out of spec DSL

Comment: This is the approach I tried. The problem I found is that Minitest ends up running all inherited test cases from `ConventionalNameTest` on every nested class.

Comment: @YuriGhensev Same, I'd love to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: @RafałCieślak Simply do not define tests in the parent class, only in the child classes. The parent class shall only have `setup`/`teardown`.

Comment: @SandroL Thanks, this is what I ended up doing! The only small inconvenience of this approach is that when I decide I need to nest tests within a class, I have to extract all existing tests to a separate one. But nonetheless it works.

Comment: @YuriGhensev if you define the nested classes like so `ContextTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase` there are no inherited tests that would be run.

Comment: What command would you use to run 1 of the subclasses?