# How can you have nested tests with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

For example, in [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), you can do this:

```
describe('Person', function () {
  describe('movement methods', function () {
    it('#run', function () {

    });
    it('#jump', function () {

    });
  });
});
```

With Minitest, it seems that you can't have a "movement methods" category. You'd have to just do:

```
class PersonTest
  def test_run
  end

  def test_jump
  end
end
```

Is there a way to nest in Minitest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. You can do something like this (not the prettiest):

```
class Person < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  class MovementMethods < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    test "#run" do
      # something
    end

    test "#jump" do
      # something
    end
  end
end
```

Also consider using [minitest/spec](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Spec/DSL.html) and you can write your tests cases more comparable to the Jasmine snippet:

```
require 'minitest/spec'

describe Person do
  describe 'movement methods' do
    it '#run' do
      # something
    end

    it '#jump' do
      # something
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: **Note**: `MovementMethods` will act as a _parallel_ TestCase instead of a _nested_ one. This means; a `setup` inside `Person` will be **never** executed for any test inside `MovementMethods`.

Comment: As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29853967
If we make `MovementMethods` inherit the `Person` class, the setup inside `Person` will be executed for tests inside `MovementMethods`.

Comment: If there are instance variables created in the parent test class, how would the child test class use them?