# Does minitest have good documentation similar to http://www.betterspecs.org/ , or how do I organize my tests

Tags: rspec, minitest

Another example is https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rspec-style-guide.

Also for larger project at what point rspec becomes better than minitest?

Answer (score 0):

No, time wasted searching was in vain. Googling for minitest vs rspec leads to this page.
https://www.codementor.io/dogweather/why-rspec-is-so-popular-tbqzmans5
which says the following:

> Poke around in the straight-from-cucumber docs, and you'll be
>   impressed with the readability. It's chock full of examples! In fact,
>   every feature has an example because this is literate code. I've never
>   found a Minitest resource that comes close. And personally, when I'm
>   using a framework — Minitest or RSpec — that has its own unique DSL
>   and practices, good docs are crucial.

While minitest spec tries to pretend it's rspec it never comes close.

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/aw8uph/why_does_no_one_use_minitest/ehm5dew/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

### Possibly the only option

is finding good examples of projects using Minitest and trying to study them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263839/how-to-organize-minitest-unit-tests useful question

Answer (score 0):

The Minitest official docs are good, not best, but good enough.

- http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest

It is linked at the top of the repository README

- https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest